# regular expressions result multiplicity

Tags: regex

Given the regular expression `"\d"`, it will match each digit in "a123b456" (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

Given the regular expression `"\d\d"` and the same teststring, it seems only to match "12" and "45" - this is at least what http://regexpal.com/ says, similarly a regex evaluator I created myself using a C++ textbook (which uses boost/regex).

Why doesn't the second one match "23" and "56", as well, or, if that behaviour is the correct one, why does the first one match each number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't the second one match "23" and "56"?

Because that's the overlapping match you are expecting regex to give you. Once a part of string is matched for a pattern, it won't be matched again for the same pattern. So, since `2` is already been included in previous match as `12`, it is gone. The regex will move onto the next character that is `3`. And following that character, it cannot see `3` included as a part of another string matching `\d\d`. The next substring matching this pattern is only found at `45`.

Try changing your string to:

```
"a1234b456"
```

and you will get three matches - `12`, `34`, and `45`.

However, you can get overlapping matches using *positive look-ahead* - `(?=\d\d)`, because *look-arounds* are *0-length* match expression. They won't consume the characters they match.

And just FYI, you can use `\d{2}` instead of `\d\d`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match all result you may use  look forward/behind

```
(?=\d\d)
```